# Removing empty strings in an array of strings and other strange data in C

Tags: c, arrays, linux, string

I'm creating a shell in C and have implemented piping. This involves dividing the argument on the left side and right side of the pipe into two separate array of strings to be executed separately with `execvp`. For some reason, the array of strings `pcmd2` contains data other than the argument I entered in the shell.

For example, I enter `ls | sort` into the shell after running the program and it outputs the following: `sort: open failed:      : No such file or directory`

Seeing this, I suspected that the array of strings `pcmd2` containing the `sort` command may have empty strings and other things that are being processed.

I print out `pcmd2` with a for-loop (with a new line after each string) and I find the following printed onto the screen:

```
sort


UJ
```

There clearly seems to be extra stuff in there. Seems like empty strings but I have no clue where the `UJ` is coming from (this gets consistenly printed out).

I've tried setting the index in `pcmd2` that's right after where `sort` is stored in the array to NULL. Like so, `pcmd2[1] = NULL` and that seemed to "fix" it since the weird extra data would no longer be processed by the `execvp` function. However, that means that I can't pipe commands with multiple arguments like `grep myshell` as it would only be able to take in the `grep` part.

I will show the full code below because I'm unsure how much context is needed in this case.

I know there's some very broken piping implementation here (I've tried some weird solution to get it work with two pipes) but I'm working to just get one pipe to work. I'm not asking for help piping in particular.

The most relevant part, I believe, is in the `splitPipeCommands` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_ARGS 20
#define MAX_PIPE_ARGS 3
#define BUFSIZE 1024

int input, output, append, usePipe;
char *inputFile;
char *outputFile;
FILE *fp1;
FILE *fp2;

int get_args(char* cmdline, char* args[]) 
{
  int i = 0;

  /* if no args */
  if((args[0] = strtok(cmdline, "\n\t ")) == NULL) 
    return 0; 

  while((args[++i] = strtok(NULL, "\n\t ")) != NULL) {
    if(i >= MAX_ARGS) {
      printf("Too many arguments!\n");
      exit(1);
    }
  }

  /* the last one is always NULL */
  return i;
}

void checkIORedirect(char* args[])
{

        input = 0;
        output = 0;
        append = 0;

        int i;
        for(i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++)
        {
                if(!strcmp(args[i], ">"))
                {
                        output = 1;
                        outputFile = args[i+1];
                        args[i] = NULL;
                }
                else if(!strcmp(args[i], "<"))
                {
                        input = 1;
            inputFile = args[i+1];
            args[i] = NULL;
            //printf("inputFile: %s\n", inputFile);
                }
                else if(!strcmp(args[i], ">>"))
                {
                        append = 1;
                        outputFile = args[i+1];
                        args[i] = NULL;
                }
        }
}

int getPipeIndexes(char* args[], int* pIndex1, int* pIndex2)
{
    *pIndex1 = -1;
    *pIndex2 = -1;  

    int i = 0;
    int pcount = 0;
    usePipe = 0;

    for(i = 0; args[i] != NULL; i++)
    {
        if(!strcmp(args[i], "|") && pcount == 0)
        {
            //printf("First pipe!\n");
            *pIndex1 = i;
            args[i] = NULL;
            pcount++;

            usePipe = 1;
        }
        else if(!strcmp(args[i], "|") && pcount == 1)
        {
            //printf("Second pipe!\n");
            *pIndex2 = i;
            args[i] = NULL;
            pcount++;
        }
        else if(!strcmp(args[i], "|") && pcount > 1)
        {
            printf("Too many pipes, only accepting first two!\n");
            args[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    return pcount;
}

void splitPipeCommands(char* args[], int* pIndex1, int* pIndex2, int pcount, char* pcmd1[], char* pcmd2[], char* pcmd3[])
{
    if(pcount == 1)
    {
        int i;
        int cmdIndex = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < *pIndex1; i++)
        {
            pcmd1[cmdIndex] = args[i];
            cmdIndex++;
        }
        cmdIndex = 0;
        //printf("2nd half of args: \n");
        for(i = *pIndex1 + 1; args[i] != NULL; i++)
        {
            pcmd2[cmdIndex] = args[i];
            //printf("%s\n", args[i]);
            cmdIndex++;
        }
        //pcmd2[1] = NULL;
        //*pcmd1 = args[0];
        //*pcmd2 = args[*pIndex1 + 1];

        /*TODO: del when you finish debugging*/
        //printf("pcmd1=%s,%s,%s\n", pcmd1[0], pcmd1[1], pcmd1[2]);
        //printf("pcmd2=%s\n", pcmd2[0]);
    }
    else if(pcount == 2)
    {
        int i;
        int cmdIndex = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < *pIndex1; i++)
        {
            pcmd1[cmdIndex] = args[i];
            cmdIndex++;
        }
        cmdIndex = 0;
        for(i = *pIndex1 + 1; i < *pIndex2; i++)
        {
            pcmd2[cmdIndex] = args[i];
            cmdIndex++;
        }
        //pcmd2[1] = NULL;
        cmdIndex = 0;
        for(i = *pIndex2 + 1; args[i] != NULL; i++)
        {
            pcmd3[cmdIndex] = args[i];
            cmdIndex++;
        }
        /*
        *pcmd1 = args[0];
        *pcmd2 = args[*pIndex1 + 1];
        *pcmd3 = args[*pIndex2 + 1];
        */
        /*TODO: del when you finish debugging*/
        //printf("pcmd1=%s,", *pcmd1);
                //printf("pcdm2=%s,", *pcmd2);
        //printf("pcmd3=%s\n", *pcmd3);
    }
}

void closeFiles()
{
    if(fp1 != NULL)
    {
        fclose(fp1);
    }

    if(fp2 != NULL)
    {
        fclose(fp2);
    }
}

void execute(char* cmdline) 
{
  int pid, pid2, async;
  char* args[MAX_ARGS];

  int nargs = get_args(cmdline, args);

  if(nargs <= 0) return;

  if(!strcmp(args[0], "quit") || !strcmp(args[0], "exit")) {
    exit(0);
  }

  /* check if async call */
  if(!strcmp(args[nargs-1], "&")) { async = 1; args[--nargs] = 0; }
  else async = 0;

  /*Pipe related*/
  int pIndex1, pIndex2;
  char* pcmd1[30];
  char* pcmd2[30];
  char* pcmd3[30];
  int pcount = getPipeIndexes(args, &pIndex1, &pIndex2);

  if(usePipe)
  {
    splitPipeCommands(args, &pIndex1, &pIndex2, pcount, pcmd1, pcmd2, pcmd3);
    if(pcount == 1)
    {
        checkIORedirect(pcmd1);
        checkIORedirect(pcmd2);
    }
    else if(pcount == 2)
    {
        checkIORedirect(pcmd1);
                checkIORedirect(pcmd2);
        checkIORedirect(pcmd3);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    checkIORedirect(args);
  }

  /*TODO: del when finished debugging*/
  //printf("pIndex1=%d,pIndex2=%d,pcount=%d\n", pIndex1, pIndex2, pcount);

  //checkIORedirect(args);

  if(output)
  {
    if((fp1 = fopen(outputFile, "w")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Output to file failed!\n");
    }
  }
  else if(append)
  {
    if((fp1 = fopen(outputFile, "a")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Append to file failed!\n");
    }
  } 

  if(input)
  {
    if((fp2 = fopen(inputFile, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Input from file failed!\n");
    }
  }

  int fd[2];
  int fd2[2];

  if(usePipe) 
  {
    if(pipe(fd) == -1)
    {
        perror("pipe failed");
        exit(1);
    }
  }

  pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0) { /* child process */

    if(input)
    {
    //printf("Input\n");
    dup2(fileno(fp2), STDIN_FILENO);
    fclose(fp2);
    input = 0;
    }
    if(output || append)
    {
    dup2(fileno(fp1), STDOUT_FILENO);
    fclose(fp1);
    output = 0;
    append = 0;
    //printf("Output or append\n");
    }

    if(usePipe)
    {
    //TODO: Make case for one pipe and two pipes
    if(pcount == 2)
    {
        if(pipe(fd2) == -1)
        {
            perror("pipe failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        pid2 = fork();
        if(pid2 == -1)
        {
            perror("fork 2 failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        if(pid2 == 0) //Child 2
        {
            close(fd[1]);
            close(fd[0]);

            close(fd2[1]);
            dup2(fd2[0], 0);
            close(fd2[0]);

            execvp(pcmd2[0], pcmd2);
            perror("exec second child failed");
            exit(-1);
        }
        else //Child 1
        {
            close(fd[1]);
            dup2(fd[0], 0);
            close(fd[0]);
            close(fd2[0]);
            dup2(fd2[1], 1);
            close(fd2[1]);

            execvp(pcmd3[0], pcmd3);
            perror("exec first child failed");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    else if(pcount == 1)
    {
        //TODO: pipe for one pipe
        //close(fd[1]);
        //dup2(fd[0], 0);
        dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        printf("pcmd1=%s\n", pcmd1[0]);
        execvp(pcmd1[0], pcmd1);
        perror("exec child failed");
        exit(-1);

    }

    }
    else
    {
    execvp(args[0], args);
        /* return only when exec fails */
    perror("exec failed");
        exit(-1);
    }

    /*
    execvp(args[0], args);
    // return only when exec fails
    perror("exec failed");
    exit(-1);
    */
  } else if(pid > 0) { /* parent process */

    if(usePipe)
    {
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(fd[1]);
        close(fd[0]);

        printf("pcmd2 contents: \n");
        int j;
        for(j = 0; pcmd2[j] != NULL; j++)
        {
            printf("%s\n", pcmd2[j]);
        }
        //FIXME: Something's wrong with pcmd2
        execvp(pcmd2[0], pcmd2);
        //execlp("sort", "sort", (char*)NULL);
        perror("exec second command failed");
    }
    else
    {
        int status;
        close(fd[0]);
        close(fd[1]);
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    }
    //wait(NULL);
    /*
    close(fd[0]);
    dup2(fd[1], 1);
    printf("pcmd1=%s\n", pcmd1[0]);
    execvp(pcmd1[0], pcmd1);
    perror("exec parent failed");
    */
    }

    if(!async)
    {
    waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
    }
    else
    {
     printf("this is an async call\n");
    }
  } else { /* error occurred */
    perror("fork failed");
    exit(1);
  }
}

int main (int argc, char* argv [])
{
  char cmdline[BUFSIZE];

  for(;;) {
    printf("COP4338$ ");
    if(fgets(cmdline, BUFSIZE, stdin) == NULL) {
      perror("fgets failed");
      exit(1);
    }
    execute(cmdline);
    usePipe = 0;
    //closeFiles();
    fflush(stdout);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately your code far awar from a **Minimal** example. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you already know that you have a problem splitting the command line, we do not need to wade through loads of code that happens after reading and splitting the command line.

Comment: You should run this under a debugger with a debug heap manager, or under valgrind. The problem is not where you think it is.

Comment: Aside: ensure you have released the "alt gr" key after your pipe in `ls |`. alt gr + space will create invisible character on command line and break your input.